# User doesn't logout properly in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to logout an user (session) when the Logout link is clicked. It seems to work when I pressed the Logout, but if I change the path, the user still alive and I don't know why.

Here's my `Controller`:

```
 /**
   * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
   */
public function logoutAction(Request $request)
{
    $helper = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
    $this->get('session')->set('id', null);
    $request->getSession()->invalidate();
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);


    return $this->render(
        'login.html.twig',
        array(
            'last_username' => null,
            'error'         => null,
        )
    );
}
```

Here's my security.yml:

```
security:
    # ...
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.form_login_authenticator
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: logout
            invalidate_session: true
```

Here's the routing.yml:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
logout:
    path: /logout
```

Comment: As I remember there was nothing to do in code just declare logout path in your security.yml

Comment: @PrzemysławKaczmarczyk I have updated my security.yml

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out have a nice day :D just remember to update also routes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `logoutAction` and check if it works. This action is provided by Symfony itself. You should only set logout path in `security.yml` what you did.

Comment: Unable to find the controller for path "/logout". The route is wrongly configured.

Comment: Try remove cache: `bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup`.